# Network of dependent values - how to only recalculate them once each?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, search, tree

I'm hoping one of you guys can figure this out.

I have an array containing lots of objects. Each object in the array contains two things:

- A value which can change.
- A list of zero or more of the other objects in my array which, if *their* values change, then *this* object needs to recalculate it's value. This can cascade many times from object to object, but there is no looping of dependencies.

<strike>I believe this is called a network (like a tree, but with multiple parents).</strike> Specifically, this is a Directed Acyclic Graph.

What I'm doing right now is this: when I change an object's value, I check every object in the array to see if it depends on the object I just changed. If it does, then I tell this child object to recalculate. Then the child tells it's children in the same way, and so on.

This works (the values update correctly), but it's very very slow when a change is made that cascades wide and deep. This is because if an object has many parents that change, it recalculates again for each one, and also tells it's children to recalculate each time, so they get several messages from just one parent. This quickly snowballs until many objects are recalculating dozens of times.

What's the best way to only recalculate each object once, after all of it's parents has recalculated?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you define "lots"?  What language are you using? What's the branching factor and how deep do the dependencies go? Do the dependencies change over time?  How often? Depending on those the answer might change as to the best way to handle this.

Comment: Lots is about 2000. It's objective-C for iPad. Number of parents is usually 1, 2 or 3. Number of children can be dozens. Generation depth probably about 10 max. Dependencies don't change. Changing a key value is currently causing 600 recalculations and taking about 25 seconds ("Recalculate" includes loading & saving values to a sqlite database). Some values are unnecessarily recalculated over 20 times but it's mostly around 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want a **Topological Sort of a Directed Acyclic Graph**.  See for example http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~lloyd/tildeAlgDS/Graph/DAG/

If your graph isn't constantly changing you should be able to simply sort it once and from then on you can execute your updates in order from left to right knowing that at each step the set of nodes you will be adding to the list to be computed are all to the right of the current position.  There's a few ways you could optimize that, maybe store them in a simple heap, pick the leftmost value off each time, recalculate it and add back any nodes it references, or as someone else has suggested, if the full dependency graph is small enough, just store it on each node in the order in which it needs to be calculated (as found using the Topological Sort).

Comment: +1 - Sorting the graph once statically makes more sense than resorting the updated portion on every change (my proposal).

Comment: +1, a Topological Sort of all the objects on launch sounds like the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Create an acyclic digraph with vertices given by the nodes in your array and an edge `i --> j` whenever a change in `i` necessitates a recalc of `j` (i.e. `i` is in the list for object `j`). The graph is acyclic iff your process is finite.

Now, when `i` changes, do a breadth first search to recalculate dependent nodes. At first pass, gather all nodes `j` such that `i --> j`. Recalculate those `j`. At the second pass, take each `j` **that changed** and get its dependents `j --> k`. Then recalculate those `k` at once. Continue by taking all the dependents of the `k`s **that changed**, and so on, until there are only leaves.

This requires you to keep a list of neighbors, which is the inverse of the information that you have. So you need to do one pass to get the directed edges (fill an array so that entry `i` has the array of all `j` for which `i --> j`).

Answer (score 0):

When a value gets updated, create a list of the other elements whose values still need to be recalculated. Before recalculating the value of an element in this list, make sure that none of the other elements on which it depends are also in the list. This will ensure that an element will only get recalculated once. Since there are no circular dependencies, there will always be at least one element in the list of elements to be recalculated which has already had all of its dependent elements recalculated.

Pseudo code:

```
Create a set S 
Add initially updated element to S
while S is not empty
    remove an element X from S whose value does not depend on any other elements in E do not exist in S
    recalculate X's value and add any elements that depend on X's value to S
```

Comment: That sounds like it would work, but wouldn't it be quite slow as well? You're comparing every dependency in an object's list against every element in the recalculation list each time you want to do a recalculation. n cubed!

Comment: You'd want to choose a data structure which allows constant time lookups, like a table, for storing both the the dependency list for each elements and the list of elements whose value needs to be recalculated. Otherwise it will get expensive as you noted.

Comment: Another problem is that before being able to do a recalculation I'd not just have to check for direct dependency, I'd have to check for dependency by proxy. So each element would need to know all it's ancestors rather than just it's direct parents.